# how to fix the issue "Failed to connect to the host via ssh" in ansible

Tags: ssh, server, ansible, host

when i execute ansible playbook from one server to other remote server i'm getting an error as

"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory\r\nHost key verification failed.", "unreachable": true"

blow is my play book

```
- hosts: igwcluster_AM:igwcluster_IS
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: True



  tasks: 

    - name: Install Oracle Java 8
     script:/data2/jenkins/workspace/PreReq_Install_To_Servers/IGW/IGW_Cluster/prereqs_Products/Java.sh
```

I'm using two host groups and each group has 2 servers.

Error log:

UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory\r\nHost key verification failed.", "unreachable": true}

Note : I have tried with

```
    host_key_checking = False
    ssh_args = -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

But still it fails. please advise me on this

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to put space after "script:" and place script exactly under "name:" so it will look like that.

```
    tasks: 
   - name: Install Oracle Java 8
     script: /data2/jenkins/workspace/PreReq_Install_To_Servers/IGW/IGW_Clust/prereqs_Products/Java.sh
```

Try to use ssh key for ssh authorization.

On the server that you are execute ansible playbook from, generate ssh key if you didn't already, you can do it with simple command:

```
ssh-keygen 
(press enter till command exit)
```

Next copy it to remote server by ssh copy id command:

```
ssh-copy-id <remote server IP/FQDN>
```

After this your ansible server  will be able to connect to remote server without password prompt and this error should not appear.

If this method doesn't work for you please share this information:

1. hosts file
2. become user that you are using to run this playbook